# GDB C++ started from Java

Tags: java, c++, debugging, intellij-idea, gdb

I am trying to debug a C++ process started from a Java server. The Java server starts the C++ process. I step through the Java code with IntelliJ, figure out the C++ process number, start gdb on that process (already started by the Java server), while IntelliJ waits at a given step in the Java code, then set a breakpoint in gdb in a C++ function I'm sure is executed (I see the trace), then continue stepping in IntelliJ, but gdb doesn't stop at my breakpoint, the process finishes on the Java side, and nothing happens on the gdb/C++ side.

Is this kind of debugging session possible (between Java and C++)? If so, did I miss something in how I'm starting gdb?

Comment: You mean you start the C++ process using gdb in java? Or do you launch gdb separately?

Comment: Updated my post: the C++ process is started by the server, I only attach gdb to it.

Comment: So you must be using attach gdb option. Which process id are you using? The java process or the launched c++ process.

Comment: Yes, I am attaching, to the pid I get from ps for the C++ process - not the pid of the Java process.

Comment: and you have surely compiled C++ code with gdb option

Comment: Yes - you mean in debug mode?

Comment: @Frank when you compiled the C++ code did you pass -g option of g++? If it is done, and you attached the process in gdb and set up the break points correctly you should get it in gdb and can trace the flow within gdb for C++ code

Comment: I'll double check my setup, but -g was the intention. gdb seems to be happy to find plenty of debug symbols and information. But I'll double check.